# At what situation points need to be reshaped like reshape(-1,1,2) in python-opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm a newer to python-opencv, so I read this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html#drawing-functions) and found some sample codes like this:

```
pts = np.array([[10,5],[20,30],[70,20],[50,10]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0,255,255))
```

it's about to show you how to draw polygons using cv2.polylines function, most of them are easy to understand, which I'm curious about is :

```
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2)) #I understand this makes pts.shape to be (4,1,2)
```

I try to remove this code and find that didn't make any difference, it works fine, either. before this reshape operation, pts's shape is (4,2), which is intuitive enough for me. Besides, when I write codes like this:

```
convex_pts = cv2.convexHull(pts) #get a convexhull from pts，pts's shape is(4,2)
print(convex_pts)       #[[[72,20]],[[20,30]],[[10,5]],[[50,10]]]
print(convex_pts.shape) #(4,1,2)
```

it seems to me that python-opencv insists to "unsqueeze" it and make it has shape like(x,1,2), that's weird to me cause when the shape is (x,2) it just works fine in the tutorial case .Any reason why is this necessary ? I searched
around and found nothing helpful, am I missing something? So I want to know why and at what situation points need to be reshaped like this?

Comment: We need to look at `opencv` docs to see what array shapes it expects and produces.  It appears to assign a specific meaning to each of the 3 dimensions.

Comment: I'm sorry, seems that my  former description  makes you got misunderstanding of my points, so I change the description  a little bit ,now it expresses  what I really want to ask.

Comment: This is an interface to C or C++ code. We have to dig into that code (the docs are vague) to see why `rows x 1 x 2` is the expected input/output for polygonal data, and what does it do if it gets `rows x 2` instead. This isn't a general `numpy` issue, It's very specific to opencv.

Comment: This may be a historical artifact.

Comment: I glanced at the `opencv` repository.  It appears to generate the Python code directly from C++ code.  If so then if you try to look at the code for `cv2.polylines` it will be listed as `builtin`, ie. imported from a `.so` compiled file.  If so, then the only we (non-developers) can tell what's going on is to experiment.  The 'deeper level details' are buried in compile code.

Comment: @ hpaulj you are right , I can only get the interface of these methods, but can't look into the implemention codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
```

This changes the shape from (4,2) to (4,1,2), which is consistent with the kind of shape several cv2 functions use. For example, if you wanted to find contours using `findContours` the output contours have shape (x,1,y).

Comment: But in my case this operation seems not to be  necessary.Any reasons  why this is a better way?I want to know some deeper level details about this.

Comment: To my limited understanding, it is a better way in the way ZdaR has explained: for each row, you have only one column, which has multiple sub-elements. When it comes to points, this approach is more intuitive to me because the number of rows indicate number of points in that dimension. So, if you wanted to have multiple planes, you can still have (x,n,y) where n is the number of planes. So, it helps in extending things from one plane to multiple ones. I am also new to OpenCV, so I might be slightly wrong. It's better to do the reshape to make it consistent with the rest of the library.

Comment: From your further explanation I can understand why python-opencv insists reshaping like this in a way, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you debug the first line of code which says:

```
pts = np.array([[10,5],[20,30],[70,20],[50,10]], np.int32)
```

and then use `pts.shape`, you will get `(4, 2)`, which means that `pts` at this point in time has 4 rows and 2 columns. Now it may be possible that the function which is taking this matrix is expecting the input in some other format, which in your case seems to be `(4, 1, 2)`, which means 4 rows, 1 column and each element with 2 sub-elements. To convert the `(4, 2)` shape in `(4, 1, 2)` shape, we use the following line of code:

```
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
```

What the above line means is that, I need a matrix with *unknown* number of rows but a single column and each element with 2 sub-elements. Now numpy internally calculates the size of *unknown* and automatically creates a matrix for you. It is just a fancy way of doing `pts.reshape((4,1,2))`

Also quoting the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred
>   from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry that my former description makes you  misunderstand  a little  about my question.  pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))  doesn't bother me, what is the reason and what kind of scene to do this kind of operation is what I want to know.

Comment: It greatly depends upon the method you are calling. For example some API may accept an 5x5 RGB image matrix of shape `(5, 5, 3)`, which means 5 rows, 5 columns and each element with 3 values, while some other library may require you to pass a 5x5 RGB image as `(25, 1, 3)` or `(25, 3, 1)` or some other format. It greatly depends upon the method/API to whom you are passing the matrix.